# PowerBuilder not storing error message from SQL Server Properly

Tags: sql-server, powerbuilder

I seem to be experiencing a strange issue when using the SqlErrText from a DataWindow in our application.

The DataWindow executes a stored procedure, lets call it vp_ut_storedProc, and in my case it throws an error when the DataWindow is updated.

When I go into the function to build the error message for our application, the SqlErrText is passed in as follows (as parameter **asErrText**):

```
SQLSTATE = 42000
Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0
TimestampNV|Someone Has Updated the Record. Please Refresh.

No changes made to the database

execute dbo.vp_ut_storedProc
```

I know that PowerBuilder receives the entire error text which is a good thing. But, when we try to save the error text into a local variable

```
isErrText = asErrText
```

The value of isErrText is: *SQLSTATE = 42000*

So, for some reason, it completely ignores everything after the second line. I figure it has something to do with the way the PowerBuilder is reading in the string, but I don't know why this happens.

I should also note that it's not just limited to this one DataWindow. It happens on quite a few of them.

Comment: Can you tell us how you're determining the value of isErrText? Have you tried assigning it to an MLE, which is built to handle multi-line text?

Comment: I am determining the value by running the debugger.

When the error text is passed in (as asErrText) everything is fine, i.e. you can see all the lines.

But as soon as isErrText (STRING) is assigned asErrText, the value of isErrText is "SQLSTATE = 42000"

This then gets displayed in a pop-up window, which a MLE is assigned  the value of isErrText.

Comment: Well, I can cite dozens of more cases where debugger display was a problem than I could cases where string passing or string assignment (you've never told us is asErrText was as expected) corrupted data. I'd open QuickWatch and enter "Clipboard (isErrText)" and Evaluate, then paste into a text editor, to get a more assured assessment of the variable value. Also, if you're suggesting a PB bug, specifying the version will help you.

Comment: Please add: PowerBuilder version, code in your Catch block, code in your error-message building function up to the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

put this in your dberror event of your datawindow

> string s_temp
>
> long l_start, l_end
>
> l_start = 42 +Pos(sqlerrtext,'Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0')
>
> l_end = Pos(sqlerrtext,sqlsyntax) - l_start - 3
>
> IF l_end <=0 THEN l_end = Len(sqlerrtext) - l_start
>
> s_temp = Mid(sqlerrtext,l_start,l_end)
>
> fw_msg(s_temp) //can write this at messagebox(this.title,s_temp) // instead
>
> RETURN 1

if its insert or select error. it ignores the syntax and outputs the error. if its a different error. it shows the rest of the errcode